# How to skip an @Transactional annotation based on flag

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using @Transactional annotation in my code having database as MongoDB. But the same code is throwing error with CosmosDB if I'm using @Transactional annotation on method. Now I want @Transactional annotation to be ignored for cosmosDB but want that annotation to be executed for MongoDB based on certain flag as I'm maintaining the same codebase for both. Is there any way to ignore the annotation?

```
@Transactional(if flag true) //should enable only when flag is true
public Customer updateCustomer(Customer customer){
        //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Transactional(prefix = "boom", name = "listener", havingValue = "MongoDB")
public Customer updateCustomer(Customer customer){
    //code
}

boom:
  listener: MongoDB
```

try this！when the 'boom.listener' do not equals 'MongoDB',the annotation will be ignore

Comment: If you register your account, you can delete your post.  In the meantime, I'm afraid I'm going to have to roll that back.

Comment: But there are not any properties as prefix, name  and havingValue in @Transactional annotation. So could you please explain if I need to add any other configuration in addition to this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to skip transactional use case for cosmos by using one property in properties file:

```
activedb: 'cosmos'(or mongo in case of MongoDB)
```

In addition to this I have added one config file

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "activedb",havingValue = "mongo") 
@Configuration 
@EnableTransactionManagement  
public class TransactionManagementConfig {

@Bean
MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
    return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
}
```

}

As we have added @ConditionalOnProperty annotation so this class will be applicable for mongo only and as we are using @EnableTransactionManagement in this class so @Transactional annotation will be application for MongoDB only.